# How much of the Gradle fixtures should I keep in my git repo?

Tags: git, gradle

I just started a new Gradle module in IntelliJ.

In the top directory it has a directory /gradle, a directory /.gradle and also the files gradlew and gradlew.bat.

Which if any of these should be included in .gitignore? I understand the general principle of the Gradle wrapper, which I use the whole time, but I don't quite understand how much of these 4 "fixtures" should be included in the git repo, with a view to making sure that anyone who does a future `pull` or `clone` gets the right setup to run things.

Maybe the usual answer is to exclude none of them? But alternatively I'm just imagining someone who kicks off a Gradle project in a directory and then does a `pull` from the repo (obviously they wouldn't then be able to do a simple `clone` because you can only `clone` to an empty directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just ignore the `.gradle` directory since it contains project-specific's cache which will be generated anyway.

The files `gradlew.bat` and `gradlew` are used to execute the Gradle Wrapper jar contained in `/gradle` on Windows and Unix OSs respectively.

The directory `/gradle` contains the Gradle Wrapper jar and a properties file which specifies the wrapper version and its distribution type.

All these wrapper related files shouldn't be ignored to provide the same Gradle Wrapper configuration for all the users of your repo and maybe for your CI too.

Even if it's a different topic, maybe this answer can give you a better understanding of the minimum necessary files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597710/4237609

Comment: Thanks, you've confirmed my suspicions about the contents of .gradle (executionHistory.bin and others suggest mutable files which might therefore take up a lot of space, which is silly if they are unnecessary) and about the need for future cloners to receive the other 3 components.  Also means you can clone to an empty directory. In short, it makes perfect sense!